# Views 2 - How to show exposed filters when results list is empty?

Tags: views

I have a page that displays all events after the current date. It has an exposed filter where you can set the date - all events after that date will be shown. This all works fine.

However, if there are no results on the initial page load (i.e. no events listed that are after the current date) then the exposed filter isn't shown (so you can't set the date to some time in past and view past events).

I found the relevant view theme template and over-rode the If($exposed) conditional but this did not do it - obviously the decision to show filters or not is made before the template but I haver no idea where.

Please could somebody enlighten me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The ominous non-sound of tumbleweed lol

Well, after a bit of faffing and a >slap forehead< "D'Oh" moment I sorted it.

I added some text in the "Empty text" setting (under "Basic Settings") and the exposed filters now show when there is no result.